# what is the meaning of はじめ皆?

Tags: meaning

水曜日は栗並さんはじめ皆さん、In this sentence, how shall I understand はじめ皆? What are the Kanji? Is は a particle, or is it the beginning of the word?

Comment: Related: https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%82%92%E3%81%AF%E3%81%98%E3%82%81%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-o-hajime-to-suru-meaning/

Answer (score 3):

はじめ (始め) here is a shortened version of をはじめとする.

In the form XをはじめとするY, X is an individual (or individuals), Y is a group that X belongs to. It basically refers to Y with X as a prime example.

A similar expression from [NHK](https://www.nhk.or.jp/politics/articles/statement/15820.html):

> 被災者をはじめとするすべての皆さんにおわびを申し上げたい

Comment: If I understand correctly, perhaps an English translation might be "Y, but most of all X"?

Comment: Yes, except for the specific-to-generic order in the original sentence.